# how to change the clock format in xamarin in visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

i want a clock who is in 24 hours format also shows the seconds, so i wrote this line of code in the texte clock

```
  android:format24Hour="hh:mm:ss"
```

my problem is, for example, now it's time **17:58:50** but the application says **5:58:50** and i want **17:58:50**.
Thanks for the help, and also i would like to know how did you find the answer because i did a lot of research for it and i didn't found the answer and i would like to become more independant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`HH`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#HH_Specifier) instead of [`hh`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#hhSpecifier) for `android:format24Hour`

> The "HH" custom format specifier (plus any number of additional "H"
> specifiers) **represents the hour as a number from 00 through 23;** that
> is, the hour is represented by a zero-based 24-hour clock that counts
> the hours since midnight. A single-digit hour is formatted with a
> leading zero.

```
android:format24Hour="HH:mm:ss"
                    //^^  HH uses 24-hour clock, from 00 to 23
```

Comment: You can refer MSDN documentation to understand [Custom date and time format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings). I already attached documentation links for `HH` and `hh` in my answer

Comment: thanks a lot it worked, and the explaination are pretty hard to understand for me but nevermind ^^